# Ansible: How to debug mutiple tasks, commands or iterations?

Tags: jenkins, automation, ansible, yaml

In a YAML playbook, I need to run multiple commands through each element in an array. I am using `with_items` to iterate, but I am getting syntax errors when I try to blend `debug` into the tasks.

Everything works when I remove the `debug` module, but than I can't see whats happening. Example provided below.

**Produces Syntax Error:**

```
- name: Iterate through array and display results  
  shell: "run command 1 on {{ item }}"  
  register: command1  
  debug:  
    msg: "Command 1 || {{ command1.stdout_lines}}"  
  shell: "run command 2 on {{ item }}"  
  register: command2  
  debug:  
    msg: "Command 2 || {{ command2.stdout_lines}}"  
  with_items: "{{ array_name }}"
```

Everything seems to be working fine when I remove the debugs, but I need to see what each command produces because it has important info.

Is there some way to print/debug the results while keeping it inside the `with_items` iterations?

**Edit:**

I also tried a few more things but they also gave me a syntax error

**Also Tried 1:**

```
- name: Iterate through array and display results  
- shell: "run command 1 on {{ item }}"  
  register: command1  
- debug:  
    msg: "Command 1 || {{ command1.stdout_lines}}"  
- shell: "run command 2 on {{ item }}"  
  register: command2  
- debug:  
    msg: "Command 2 || {{ command2.stdout_lines}}"  
  with_items: "{{ array_name }}"
```

**Also Tried 2:**

```
- name: Iterate through array and display results  
  - shell: "run command 1 on {{ item }}"  
    register: command1  
  - debug:  
      msg: "Command 1 || {{ command1.stdout_lines}}"  
  - shell: "run command 2 on {{ item }}"  
    register: command2  
  - debug:  
      msg: "Command 2 || {{ command2.stdout_lines}}"  
  with_items: "{{ array_name }}"
```

Comment: Please have a read at [ask] as well as the [markdown editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), as your question is currently written, the error, which comes from a syntax in your code, cannot be pointed as you did not format your code in the question as it is in your Jenkins integration.

Comment: I fixed the format of the code

Comment: So, in Ansible, you can only have one module per item in the list (`tasks` is a list of tasks, each being an Ansible module). To fix your issue, you have to have a new item in the list (a dash `-`), in front of all the `debug` and `shell` tasks.

Comment: Ok thank you @β.εηοιτ.βε , I tried a few things with the dashes and also produced errors. I edited the original post to provide examples of how I formatted the playbooks. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can fix all those syntax errors yourself by making your playbook valid after spending the necessary time to [read the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue, Ansible does not allow iterations through multiple tasks. I had to put the tasks in a separate yml playbook and use **include_tasks:** to call the playbook.